# Creating a Qweb Report based on Category for custom module

Tags: xml, report, odoo, qweb

***Hello Odooers and XMLers.***

How can i group these records based on Category and Sub-Category(custom fields) in a Custom Module ?

***Records Tree View:***
[image]

***Example Desired Report Design:***

[image]

i Tried this Code but didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<template id="report_main">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
        <t t-set="main_seco" t-value="[]"/>
        <t t-foreach="bondid" t-as="l">
            <t t-set="work1_name" t-value="work1_name+[l.work1_id]"/>
        </t>
    <t t-foreach="set(work1_name)" t-as="work1">
    <div><strong t-esc="work1.name"/></div>
    <t t-foreach="o.bondid" t-as="l">
        <!-- <t t-if="work1.id==l.work1_name"> -->
            <div><span t-field="l.work1"/></div>
        <!-- </t> -->
    </t>
</t>
</t>
</template>
</odoo>
Blockquote
```

Answer (score 0):

Frist, you use `t-foreach` for get all item parent with `t-as="i"`

Second, in `t-foreach` you use `search` and with domain is `category.parent = i.parent`

The same with sub-category

You can view my example:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efI2E.png)

If you lose, you can contact to me (transon821996@gmail.com). I will support you.

Sorry for my english. I'm trying learn it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I will try it and will let you know.
P.S: Your English is Doing great by the way.